# I get a syntax error whenever I use `CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO` in mysql

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7

This is the MYSQL query:

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO SOURCE_HOST='3.94.185.28', SOURCE_USER='replica_user', SOURCE_PASSWORD='password', SOURCE_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', SOURCE_L
OG_POS=154
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE TO SOURCE_HOST='3.94.185.28', SOURCE_USER='replica_user', SOURCE_PASSWORD' at line 1
```

I'm MySQL 5.7.40

I also get a syntax error whenever i type any code containing `REPLICA` for example, `STOP REPLICA;`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using MySQL 8.0 syntax on MySQL 5.7 environment.

`CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO` is first introduced on [MySQL 8.0.23](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-replication-source-to.html)

In [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html) the following syntax applies

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
  MASTER_HOST='source2.example.com',
  MASTER_USER='replication',
  MASTER_PASSWORD='password',
  MASTER_PORT=3306,
  MASTER_LOG_FILE='source2-bin.001',
  MASTER_LOG_POS=4,
  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10;
```

> I also get a syntax error whenever i type any code containing REPLICA
> for example, STOP REPLICA;

From MySQL 8.0.22, STOP SLAVE is deprecated and the alias STOP REPLICA should be used instead.

[STOP SLAVE 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stop-slave.html)

[STOP SLAVE 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stop-slave.html)

Comment: Wonderful. It worked. Thank you very much